# Maze code not solving maze, only printing

Tags: c++, class, templates, stack, maze

I'm having problems with code I'm writing to solve give mazes using class Templates and stacks. The algorithm worked well enough before I implemented code to be able to read mazes from files. Now it doesn't solve the maze, it only outputs "Stack is full! Can not push" and prints the maze. The algorithm I'm adhering goes like:

1. Define the two-dimensional int array M as given
   above, and two int stacks which will store the row
   and column index of the locations we have checked.
2. Search the array M to locate the entry 2 to find your
   starting point
3. Push the current location (i.e., the row and column
   index) onto the () stacks.
4. Check if the value stored at the current location is
   a 3; if it is, we are done. If not, set it to 2.
5. Check the current location's four neighbours in order (e.g., clockwise from north). If any is a 1 or a
   3, pop that location onto the stack and move there
   next.
6. If none of the neighbours store a 1, we are at a
   dead-end: set the value at that location to 0, and
   pop the new location from the stack.

Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#define MAX_STACK 10
void PrintMaze(int **Maze, int M, int N);
template <class T>

class MyStack {
private:
  T *contents;
  int top, maxsize;
public:
    ~MyStack(void);
    MyStack (void);
    MyStack (unsigned int StackSize);
    bool checkEmpty(void);
    bool checkFull(void);
    void push(T c);
    T pop(void );
    int scon(void);
};

template <class T> MyStack<T>::~MyStack(void)
{
    delete [] contents;
}
template <class T> MyStack<T>::MyStack(void)
{
  top=0;
  contents = new T [MAX_STACK];
  maxsize = MAX_STACK;
}

template <class T> MyStack<T>::MyStack(unsigned int StackSize)
{
  top=0;
  maxsize = StackSize;
  contents = new T[StackSize];
}

template <class T> bool MyStack<T>::checkEmpty(void)
{
    return MAX_STACK == 0;
}

template <class T> bool MyStack<T>::checkFull(void)
{
    return MAX_STACK == 10;
}

template <class T> void MyStack<T>::push(T c)
{
  if(checkFull())
  {
      std::cout << "Stack is fulL! Can not push" << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    contents[top]=c;
    top++;
  }
}

template <class T> T MyStack<T>::pop(void)
{
  top--;
  return(contents[top]);
  if(checkEmpty())
  {
    std::cout << "Stack empty! Can not pop" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    top--;
    return(contents[top]);
  }
}

template <class T> int MyStack<T>::scon(void)
{
    return(*contents);
}

int main(void )
{

    // Open the file
    std::ifstream InFile;
    InFile.open("C:/Users/Desktop/Computer Science/Maze6.txt");
    if (InFile.fail())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error - cannot open Maze.txt" << std::endl;
        return(1);
    }

    // Read the size of the maze
    int Rows, Cols;
    InFile >> Rows >> Cols;
    std::cout << "The maze has " << Rows << " rows and " << Cols << " columns." << std::endl;

    // Dynamically assign memory for the array
    int **M = new int*[Rows];
    for(int i = 0; i < Rows; ++i)
    {
        M[i] = new int[Cols];
    }

    /// Read in the data
    for (int i=0; i<Rows; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<Cols; j++)
    {
        char c;
        InFile >> c;
        M[i][j] = (int)(c-'0');
    }

    // Display the maze
    std::cout << "Here is the maze: ";
    PrintMaze(M, Rows, Cols);

    //////////////////////////////
    MyStack<int> s1;
    MyStack<int> s2;
    for(int Rows=0; Rows<sizeof(M); Rows++)
    {
        for(int Cols=0; Cols<sizeof(M); Cols++)
        {
            if(M[Rows][Cols] == 2)
            {
                s1.push(Rows);
                s2.push(Cols);
                if(Rows-1 == 1)
                {
                    s1.push(Rows-1);
                    s2.push(Cols-1);
                    M[Rows-1][Cols] == 2;
                }
                if(Cols+1 == 1)
                {
                    s1.push(Rows);
                    s2.push(Cols+1);
                    M[Rows][Cols+1] == 2;
                }
                if(Rows+1 == 1)
                {
                    s1.push(Rows+1);
                    s2.push(Cols);
                    M[Rows-1][Cols] == 2;
                }
                if(Cols-1 == 1)
                {
                    s1.push(Rows);
                    s2.push(Cols-1);
                    M[Rows][Cols-1] == 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    M[Rows][Cols] = 0;
                    s1.pop();
                    s2.pop();
                }
            }
            if(M[Rows][Cols] == 3)
            {
                std::cout << "Maze completed! Item found at row: " << Rows << " column: " << Cols << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Column path: " << s2.scon() << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Row path: " << s1.scon() << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                M[Rows][Cols] == 2;
            }
        }
    }
    //////////////////////////////


    // Deallocate memory

    for(int i =0; i<6; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<6; j++)
        {
            std::cout <<M[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return (0);
}

void PrintMaze(int **Maze, int M, int N)
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i<M; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            std::cout << Maze[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: If you are not required to write your own stack and dynamic array, strongly consider using `std::stack` and `std::vector` from the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: yeah it was required to write my own stack and dynamic array. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(M)` is wrong, it will give you the size of the pointer `M` itself, not the size of what it points to. You need to explicitly use the `Rows` and `Cols` variables, using their *original* values, and use different values for iterating over the rows and the columns.

As in

```
//////////////////////////////
MyStack<int> s1;
MyStack<int> s2;
for(int i=0; i<Rows; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<Cols; j++)
    {
        // Use i and j as indexes...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, iterating that way makes more sense. the code still isn't correctly solving the maze but I feel like that has more to do with the way I implemented the algorithm.